# Sending email using Python Script

Tags: python, smtplib

I am trying to write out a function that will automate sending emails to a specific account. When I run my code I get the error message:

```
Email could not send
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "email.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.utils'; 'email' is not a package
```

This is the code I have written:

```
import smtplib
import logindetails
def send_email(subject, msg):
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(logindetails.EMAIL_ADDRESS, logindetails.PASSWORD)
        message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, msg)
        server.sendmail(logindetails.EMAIL_ADDRESS, logindetails.EMAIL_ADDRESS, message)
        server.quit()
        print('Email sent successfully')
    except:
        print('Email could not send')

subject = 'Testing'
msg = 'Hello there how are you today'
send_email(subject, msg)
```

Comment: `File "email.py", line 1, in <module>` your script is called `email.py` which makes `smtplib.py` not being able to import the real `email.py` :)

Answer (score 3):

Most likely one of your own modules in the module search path (including the current working directory) is actually called `email`. This will cause Python to pick up that module instead, and it will shadow the `email` module from the standard library, leading to that import error.

Rename that module to something else, and you should be good.

Comment: No just rename your filename to something other than email.py